# Send select-option object and get list without ajax (thymeleaf)

Tags: jquery, spring, thymeleaf

```
    <form name='form' th:object="${role}" method='GET'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Rol sec</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control"
                            th:field="${roleList}" >


                        <option value="0">
                            Rol seciniz
                        </option>
                        <option th:each="role : ${roleList}"
                                th:value="${role.id}"
                                th:text="${role.name}">

                        </option>
                    </select>

                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Sec" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

I have a page like this. It gets all roles from endpoind:

```
    @GetMapping(value = {"/assign-roles"})
...
    modelView.addObject("roleList", roleService.findAll());

    return modelView;
}
```

And when user selects one of the role and clicks submit (i could not do without submit button), it should bring the menus which are assigned to that role. I need something like this:

```
               th:action="${'/menu/id'}"
```

when submit button clicked. And it will go to another endpoind:

```
  @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ModelAndView getMenusForRole(@PathVariable String id) {


//same modelview

        modelView.addObject("menuList", menuService.findAllMenusForRole(id));

        return modelView;
    }
```

So, next to that select-option, static list should be shown. I could not find a way to do without ajax.

When button is clicked, I am returning same modelview but this time, select-option is selected and next to it, menus are seen.

And for next, user can delete add to that menu list after i show the menus.

So 3 steps:

> 1- get view, `assign-roles` and get all roles to show at option-select
>   2- when one role is clicked, go to backend, get all menus for that
>   role, than put to next to roles 
>   as checkbox. 
>   3- When checkboxes are
>   selected and `add` or `remove` is clicked, update the list.

Should I use ajax? Instead of returning all modelview?

I can use same endpoind and put to same modelview in the backend. Than can check in the frontend if exists. If exists, I can show the menus. After add button is clicked, I will update and return again?

Comment: Why don't you want to use AJAX? It certainly looks like a proper situation to make use of it.

Comment: Because I like thymeleaf. It can do anything without defining js scripts

Comment: As much as I like thymeleaf too, no it can't. Thymeleaf will help you parse templates and sending nicely done html to the client, but once you are in the client say goodbye to thymeleaf: if you want dynamic behaviour you've to use js and ajax or resign yourself to make a lot of whole-page-refreshes calling the controller with normal submits.